# How to remove white space from beamer background?

Tags: beamer

I'd like to include a background image in a beamer file.
However, a white space occurs on the left and on the top the image, which I cannot remove.
How to get rid of this gap or indentation?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
{\usebackgroundtemplate{\tikz\node{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tikz automatically adds some space around the content of a node. You can disable this by setting the `inner sep` to zero:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
{\usebackgroundtemplate{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```